# Run Ubuntu on old windows laptop

Tags: boot, wireless, windows, laptop

I have an HP Pavilion G6 laptop, which I bought in 2012. I have been using it since then till the end of 2018 and didn't use it for 3 years afterwards. Till 2018, I was using Win 8, which was working fine with minimal lag.
Recently I opened the laptop, it took around 45 minutes to just boot and then it was really slow to use. So, I installed an ubuntu linux on it.
But it still takes 35-40 minutes to just boot. It works fine until I open an app, which again takes a lot of time to load.
The laptop that I have has 4GB DDR3 RAM and 500 GB HDD.
I don't want to throw it away. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried:                                                                                          sudo apt-get update                                                                               
 ,sudo apt-get upgrade                                                                              
, and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Which ubuntu version did you installed ? And which desktop manager do you use on it. Maybe, it worth to try some lightweight combination of software, like kubuntu or lubuntu..

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install? Did you install one of the official flavors like Xubuntu or Lubuntu? Open a terminal and enter the command `systemd-analyze blame`. Press the key Q to quit. Then copy the output of the command [directly in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1443631/edit) and format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. Also add the Ubuntu version information in your question.

Comment: When you opened the laptop did you change anything? RAM, cpu cooler/fan. Or did you just clean it? The question is 'what changed between putting it away ( almost no lag ) to now ( 45 mins to boot Windows/ 30-35 for Ubuntu )? Do you hear any unusual noises from the hard disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the hard drive to me. If you have a spare usb stick lying around I would try making a bootable usb drive and see if things launch faster. If things work better from a usb drive replace the hard drive (might as well get an ssd) because it is probably failing.
That is what I have had to do before.
When you follow user68186's directions I expect this is where you will end up.